# Can you add data to a Cognos 10 bar chart?

Tags: charts, cognos, cognos-10

Is it possible to dummy code a number to appear in a bar chart in Cognos? I am looking at department expense totals for 2015 and 2016 and want to put a 3rd bar for what the budget for the department is. This data is not loaded into our data warehouse though so I am searching for a possible work around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you to have one set of bars, then you have to use a union:

1. Create a new query
2. Add a new data item to hold the budget value
3. Add 'dummy' versions of all other columns. The data types have to match your existing query
4. Make sure that the order of all columns matches up with the order of the original query
5. Union your new query with the original query
6. Use the query representing the result of the union as the source for your chart

Another option you have is to use a baseline to represent the budget. Instead of a separate bar, you have a line that goes across the whole chart at the budget value. Baselines can be configured under the Chart Annotations section of the chart properties sheet.

Lastly, you can choose a chart type that accepts multiple measures.